# Draw Letters Game by action script 3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, drawing

i am a beginner in Action script 3 and i have a task to create a small game for kids  which let them draw Alphabet Letters in English by tracing points ,and i need help in this game coding, any ideas ?

Comment: Can you show any work done so far that we can give you ideas on? As a beginner - we have to see to what extend can you use Action Script for that game and where you get stucked - then we can give you ideas.

Comment: `i need help in this game coding, any ideas?` Your question is not answerable. You forgot to say where or how you're stuck, then we can give you ideas.